# quarkus,How do I get the request body in this ContainerRequestContext.class

Tags: quarkus

this is my code

Is there any way to get from ContainerRequestContext

thanks for you help

```
@Provider
public class LoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingFilter.class);

    @Inject
    JsonWebToken jwt;

    @Context
    UserInfo userInfo;

    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Context
    HttpServerRequest request;


    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        String method = requestContext.getMethod();
        String path = uriInfo.getPath();
        String address = request.remoteAddress().toString();
        String name = jwt.getName();
        LOGGER.info("{}:{}, From {}, By {}",method,path,address,name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
IOUtils.toString(requestContext.getEntityStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.BlockingNotAllowedException: Attempting a blocking read on io thread      It should be a reactive question

Comment: You can make this work if you add `@Blocking` to `LoggingFilter`